# Filter results in Solrping

Tags: solr

I want unique suggestions. The scenario is like this:

```
Area 
abc
cde
efg
abc
abc
```

Area field is indexed, ngramed.

Now suppose, user query is 'abc' then I am getting 3 times 'abc' in suggestion.

I have heard of field collapsing and grouping but I learnt that it could only be apply on fields which are not NGRAMED.

Is it confirmed? If yes, then what should be my approach to get unique results.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the Solr [faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters), by which you can facet on the Area field. Also use the [facet.prefix](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.prefix) query to filter the results for terms starting with the term. This would work on ngramed terms as well as return unique terms with the number of the count the terms appears which you can ignore.